# Automatically add activity to Manifest?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest

I remember (although I am not sure any more) I read that IntelliJ IDEA IDE can automatically add newly crated `Activities` into the `Manifest` file. However, this does happen in my projects. Is there a special command for that or this feature does not exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the **Project View** use **New** | **Android Component** | **Activity**, type name, like `Sample`, you will get a Java source file created that `extends Activity` and `<activity android:name=".view.Sample"/>` line in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In older IDEA versions there were separate New menu items for Activity, Service, etc.

Comment: Perfect. It would be better if it creates a string entry (res/values/strings.xml)) as Label name instead of hard coding the string into `Label` attribute. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ V12, and the 'Android Component' option shows for the context menu only when the pointer is over the 'src' folder and its subsections. Maybe this is something that has changed over versions. Adding and deleting activities works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the shameless plug but if you want to add your activity in the manifest you can use a plugin I wrote for myself.

When you have an Activity or a class that inherits from Activity at some point that has no mention in the AndroidManifest.xml you can press (<kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and press 'add to manifest'. This adds the activity to the manifest.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3491432/AndroidManifestFitter.jar

Source code: https://github.com/JorgeDC/AndroidManifestFitter